# Broker per node model?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have gone through couple of Kafka tutorials on google like [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_tutorial.pdf). 
Based on them I have got some questions in context of Kafka :-

**1.  What is broker ?**

Per mine understanding, Each Kafka instance hosting topic(zero or more    partition) is broker .

**2.  Broker per node ?**

I believe in practical scenario under clustering , ideally each node will have one kafka instance where each instance will hold  two partitions

```
a. One partition(working as leader)  
b. Another partition working as follower for partition on another anode.
```

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Correct. A broker is an instance of the Kafka server software which runs in a Java virtual machine

2) Incorrect. A node is really the same thing as a broker. If you have three Kafka brokers running as a single cluster (for scalability and reliability) then it's said that you have a 3 node Kafka cluster. Each node is the leader for some partitions and the backup (replica) for others.

However, there are other kinds of nodes besides Kafka broker nodes. Kafka uses Zookeeper so you might have 3 or five Zookeeper nodes as well. A cluster of Zookeepers is often called an Ensemble.

In later versions of Kafka there are now different types of nodes so it's also normal to say there are 3 broker nodes, 5 Zookeeper nodes, 2 Kafka Connect nodes, and a 10 node (or instance) Kafka Streams application.

Comment: I believe with later version of Kafka. We can eliminate Zookeeper. I mean Kafka in itself provides  clustering where as client code can connect to kafka cluster without need of Zookeeper. Right ?

Comment: new versions of Kafka eliminate zookeeper dependency for client producers and consumers but the brokers still require zookeeper.

Comment: So broker internally use/set up the zookeeper for clustering. We don't need to setup the zookeeper manually while installing kafka ? Or we can say zookeeper comes integrated with kafka ?

Comment: You need to setup zookeeper too but it's not hard. It comes bundled in the download with Kafka. See https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Comment: ok let me ask this - Is it possible to setup the kafka cluster without zookeeper ?

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: Can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702887/role-of-zookeeper-in-cluster ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147418/discussion-between-user3198603-and-hans-jespersen).

Answer (score 1):

1. Each Kafka instance hosting zero or more topics is called a broker.
2. Each node can host multiple brokers, but in a production environment it makes sense to run one broker per node. Each broker typically hosts multiple topics/partitions though. Having only two partitions per Kafka broker is a waste of resources.

I hope this helps.