# Role of ZooKeeper in cluster?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

If I have cluster hosting 1 topic which has three partitions. So ZooKeeper(ZK) cluster hosting 3 broker instances.

Per mine understanding ,

1. Producer will interact with ZooKeeper to publish the message on broker.
2. ZK will decide internally which partition it needs to publish the message based on load on each broker instance. Broker will also interact with ZK
   to maintain offset per consumer instance
3. Similarly Consumer will interact with ZooKeeper to consume the message from broker. ZK will get the message out from right broker based on load.

But I got confused after reading below bold text from section `Workflow of Queue Messaging / Consumer Group`
   at [kafka tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_tutorial.pdf). Is mine understanding above wrong ? Based on below looks like producer/consumer does not interact directly with zookeeper. Is it otherway around
 where ZK interact with producer/consumer. If yes who(Zookeeper or broker) which broker instance message needs to be published or consumed ?

> ZooKeeper service is mainly used to notify producer and consumer about
>   the presence of any new broker in the Kafka system or failure of the
>   broker in the Kafka system. As per the notification received by the
>   Zookeeper regarding presence or failure of the broker then producer
>   and consumer takes decision and starts coordinating their task with
>   some other broker. Basically Apache Zookeeper s a distributed
>   configuration and synchronization service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be very mixed up in that most of the things you think are done by Kafka brokers are actually done by the clients and that most of the things you think are done by Zookeeper are actually done by the brokers.

Kafka is a very scalable system because the clients do a lot of the processing. The parts not done by the clients are done by the brokers (and the special broker components called the Controller and the Coordinators). Zookeeper does very little other than store state and some configuration for the brokers (in a very reliable way)

Addressing your points:

1) Incorrect. The new Producer does not interact directly with ZooKeeper. Producer talks directly to the brokers to publish messages or make meta-data requests to find which broker is the leader for a partition it wants to publish to.

2) Incorrect. ZK does not "decide" anything. ZK is a replicated fault tolerant storage system that the brokers use to save information and state for the cluster. The decision on which partition to publish into is done in the Producer and depends on the key of the message being published and the client side partitioner algorithm. Partitions are not assigned based on load, they are assigned based on the key (or if the key is null) then using a round robin algorithm. The Broker will NOT interact with ZK to maintain offset per consumer instance. Consumers keep track of their own offsets and store them (occasionally, via offset commits) in the _consumer_offsets topic on the brokers.

3) Incorrect. New Consumer will NOT directly interact with ZooKeeper to consume the message from broker. ZK will NOT get the message out from right broker based on load. Consumers will talk directly to the brokers, join and leave consumer groups via RPCs sent to the brokers using the kafka protocol.

Comment: Yes producer can (optionally) specify specific partition it wants to publish to irrespective of message key. producer.send(new ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]>(topic, partition, key1, value1), callback1); see https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

Comment: Point 1/2 `Producer talks directly to the brokers to publish messages or make meta-data requests to find which broker is the ...`. Say kafka hosting 3 broker instances(partitions) for 1 topic, do you mean producer will decide the partition number based on key of meesage and  simply publish the message to kafka. Then kafka will decided who is the leader for that partition and publish it ? In that case message from same producer can go to different partitions based on message key . Is that correct ? Can producer specify specific partition it wants to publish irrespective of message key also ?

Comment: Point 2 `and store them (occasionally, via offset commits) in the _consumer_offsets topic on the brokers...` I think broker persists these committed offsets on zookeeper  ?

Comment: Point 3 `Consumers will talk directly to the brokers ..` How broker will decide from which partition message has to be pulled from ?

Comment: Not in 0.9 or higher. Broker persists these committed offsets in a Kafka topic dedicated to storing offsets

Comment: Client decides which partition to pull from

Comment: You have read some old information about Kafka. It's all different now

Comment: `Client decides which partition to pull from..`  Client intention is generally to pull the message in fast mode (same as  producer).  At producer side we are achieving the scalability by dividing the load based among partitions based on message key. But how client(consumer) will know which partition has much load and decide which partition to pull from ?

Comment: By doing a meta data request and getting the data it needs to decide from the brokers

Comment: How about you read about metadata requests https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-MetadataAPI

Comment: But the meta data does not tell which partition has how much load or from where last request is pulled from  which i believe generally should be criteria for any consumer(something like web server cluster where load balancer pulls the request either in round robin fashion/load) ?

Comment: Kafka simply does not work that way. It's not a web server and it doesn't scale by doing round robin load balancing of consumers. If it did that you would lose the ordering of the messages which is an important feature in stream processing

Comment: ok fair point. In that case consumer also need to be aware of partitioning logic which producer used to pick the message from right partition. Also can you please confirm first point of mine first comment. Thanks for patience.

Comment: There is a leader for each partition. Producer client makes meta data request to brokers to get info about how many partitions are in a topic (say 3 as an example) and where the leader is for each partition (let's assume 1 leader is on each broker). Then producer decides which partition to send the message to (via key, or round robin if no keys). Let's say it determines the key should go to partition 2. Then it publishes directly to whichever broker has the leader for partition 2. Everything is done by the client.

Comment: Can you throw some light on mine last comment also ` In that case consumer also need to be aware of partitioning logic which producer used to pick the right message from right partition` otherwise how it will decide where to pick the message from ?

Comment: Consumers are logically decoupled from producers so they do not have to have the same partitioning algorithm. If you want to force them to pick the same partition as a publisher for the same "right" message then you can consume from a partition by its number (just as you can publish to a partition by number). This is not how most consumers are written though. Usually you have multiple identical consumers in a consumer group and each one gets one of the partitions for parallel processing

Comment: That's correct. But when you say `you have multiple identical consumers in a consumer group and each one gets one of the partitions for parallel processing`  how consumer_2 will know which partition is free and not subscribed yet ?

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/72378/understanding-kafka-consumer-partition-assignment.html

Answer (score 1):

Kafka uses zookeeper for:
1. Leader selection: this is required for topic partitions where replication factor is higher. Idea is to choose a node as leader for partition which keeps track of offset management and replication to followers. ZK is used to elect the leader to make sure there is one available leader at all time. 
2. Cluster Memberships: to manage the brokers
3. Topics: Manage the topic which exists on the cluster, number of partitions, number of replicas, replica locations, etc...

Consumer specific:
You can choose to manage consumer offsets on ZK. Therefore ZK will manage the latest offset and members of the consumer group.

I hope this answers your query

Comment: "You can choose to manage consumer offsets on ZK" please can you link me the documentation about this ?

Comment: I was referring to the old kafka consumer by this comment, where consumer group management was performed by Zookeeper.